# Does Raspberrypi 4 support boot from GPT partitioned disk?

Tags: boot-issues, bootloader

I'm interested if Raspberry pi 4 bootloader does support boot from GPT partitioned disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boot partition MUST be the first partition on a **MBR medium**.

The root partition can be on another medium, which can be GPT, provided it is identified correctly (PARTUUID or device).

Comment: @PhilipCouling At the time this was posted  you could only boot from SD. Changes to the EEPROM have now made this possible. It is still impossible to boot from GPT, which was the question.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I have answered over 2000 questions on this site. Many are now obsolete. There are not enough hours in the day to revise every answer when the Foundation makes a change. It is enough effort to keep the tutorials up to date.

Comment: You've actually spend more time arguing with me than it would have taken to make the edit I suggested.  I'm not telling you off for not doing it sooner, just now we've had this conversation the usual etiquette is to update the answer to bring it into line.  I'd do it myself only SO guidelines say I shouldn't make edits that directly disagree with the original author's intent.

Comment: I have had no luck trying to boot from a GPT Drive. I am typically left with a drive with partition issues.  On firstboot the pi tries to resize /dev/sda2 and fails. This leaves the following error on /dev/sda2 in GParted: superblock checksum does not match the superblock.
to open /dev/sda2. Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock. I am most interested in a solution.  I can use a full GPT as a data drive without issue. I need to know more about correcting superblock issues.

Comment: This, as milliways has commented, is old (actually very old) information. It is possible, on current Pi4's, to boot off of GPT. A pain (I have a bash script) to create a GPT drive, but possible. I've done it. I'm sure many have also done it. (I'm answering as I can't comment - I don't have a "50 reputation" - so others don't get misled.)